# Getting the absolute position of cursor in tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I have a code from my supervisor that I am facing problems in understanding. I wish to draw a rectangle where my cursor is, using the `create_rectangle` method for which I give arguments/coordinates as:

`rect = create_rectangle(x, y, x + 10, y + 10, fill = 'blue', width = 0)`

I wish `x` and `y` here to be the current coordinates of my cursor with respect to my root window.

The way `x` and `y` are calculated in my code before passing them to this function is:

```
x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
```

And I can't for the life of me understand why this has been done. I tried doing just

```
x = root.winfo_pointerx()
y = root.winfo_pointery()
```

and also just

```
x = root.winfo_rootx()
y = root.winfo_rooty()
```

but neither of these draw the rectangle where the cursor is. I also tried looking into the documentation but can't really understand what's happening.

So why is `x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()` and `y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()` being done here?

Comment: `winfo_pointer()` = position of the cursor on the screen. `winfo_root()` = position of the window on the screen. `winfo_pointer()-winfo_root()` = position of the cursor in your window.

Answer (score 7):

You are asking about the difference between **absolute SCREEN** and **relative** mouse pointer's positions.

The notation:

```
x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
```

reflects the mouse pointer's absolute position in contrast with `winfo_pointerx()` and `w.winfo_pointery()` (or [`w.winfo_pointerxy()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html)) which reflect the mouse pointer's coordinates relatively to  your  ***`w`*'s root window**.

But what does absolute and relative notions mean?

`winfo_rootx()` and `winfo_rooty()` return, respectively,  the `x` and `y` coordinate sof upper left corner of this widget on the root window. **But these `x` and `y` coordinates are calculated regarding your laptop's SCREEN**

`winfo_pointerx()` and `winfo_pointery()` return the x and y coordinates of the mouse pointer relatively to the main **root's window** NOT to the **SCREEN**.

So by running only `winfo_pointerxy()` you are taking in consideration only the **root window** itself but you are **ignoring** the rest (the **SCREEN**).

But the problem is that when you move your mouse on the **root window**, you must not forget that your system is calculating the coordinates based on your laptop's **SCREEN**.

## Alternative approach

Note that you can substitute your current code:

```
def get_absolute_position(event=None):
    x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
    y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
    return x, y
```

By an other approach taking advantage from the event's coordinates:

```
def get_absolute_position(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    return x, y
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def f(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)

root.bind("<Motion>", f)
```