# Mouse position using python

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

I have written the following two scripts to show the current mouse position in the console:

Using `tkinter`:

```
import tkinter
import time

print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
p=tkinter.Tk()

try:
    while True:
        x, y = p.winfo_pointerxy()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

[image: Output at the most right bottom point]

`1535, 863`

Using `pyautogui`

```
import pyautogui, sys
import time

print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

[image: Output at the most right bottom point]

`1919, 1079`

Why these two are different? What is the difference between `pyautogui.position()` and `tkinter.winfo_pointerxy()`?

The referred question in comment doesn't answer my question because I want to know the difference between the two functions and how to get similar output.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these two toolkits but generally a widget or component has its own x/y origin compared to actual screen x/y origin. When grabbing from a widget/component its relative to its x/y position on the screen.

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but how can we tell that your mouse is actually in the same position?

Comment: I can ensure you that, but you won't have to trust me. You can just use the code I have attached and check by pointing the mouse at the bottom right point. @Grismar

Comment: You're basically asking why you're getting a position relative to the windows vs. the screen, just like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428593/getting-the-absolute-position-of-cursor-in-tkinter (note that your example code doesn't open a window and doesn't serve to demonstrate the problem)

Comment: I am not sure but both of the codes should open a console and show you the current mouse position on the console. @Grismar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the absolute position of cursor in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428593/getting-the-absolute-position-of-cursor-in-tkinter)

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to get the coordinates of the mouse in tkinter. Are you interested in better ways?

Comment: Sure. I also want to know why they are different, I want to get the same output using ```tkinter``` as ```pyautogui``` @BryanOakley

Comment: I got (1919, 1079) using `winfo_pointerxy()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Stated In The Original Documentation Of Both Libraries
`w.winfo_pointerxy():` Returns a tuple (x, y) containing the coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to w's **root window**.
[Tkinter Documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html)
While `pyautogui.position()` gives with respect to the left top corner of your screen.
[PyAutoGUI Documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)
Use This `x = p.winfo_pointerx() - p.winfo_rootx()`
`y = p.winfo_pointery() - p.winfo_rooty()`
To Know More [Getting the absolute position of cursor in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428593/getting-the-absolute-position-of-cursor-in-tkinter)

Comment: Is it possible to add sample code?

Comment: Value of ```x```, ```y``` is always showing ```0, 0```

Comment: Please Check Now.

Comment: The mentioned link doesn't answer my question. Have you tried the code you have attached? It's generating the same output as mine?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    get1 = input('\nGet Cords Press Enter! \n')
    pos1 = pyautogui.position()
    print(str(pos1[0]) + ',' + str(pos1[1]))
```

This will print your x, y cords every time you press enter to the console. When you're done, you can quit by pressing Q.

Not a lot of code needed and works pretty much flawlessly.